# Are there any engineers from NASA or SpaceX here?

Tags: discussion

I believe I can't make this question here because it's off topic of the off topic section (I dont see any tag which really fits it) but I'm giving it a shot, forgive me if it has to be closed. Just for curiosity , are there any engineers from NASA or SpaceX here? I have a couple of engineers from NASA in my personal Facebook (well actually one current engineer and a former one), so I guess it's not impossible at all that some of them are actually answering here? Just wondering if we could be getting some in depth details we wouldnt be getting elsewhere.